# Where to find the values to subscription id, client id, secret and tenant id?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

Actually I am trying to create an infrastructure in azure using terraform so I wanted these keys for programmatic access.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Answer (score 3):

**SubscriptionId** and **TenantId** belongs to your azure subscription which you can either get from azure portal directly or from powershell.

[image]

**ClientId** and **Client Secret** are related to the application registered where you will be providing access[role] to your application to perform certain functionality for you. You can convert the secure string password to plain string as below:
[image]

When you will register any application in your Azure Active Directory you can have all the details, after creating it- ClientId, Secret, Subscription Id and Tenant Id.

See more details on doing it from [Azure Portal](https://community.microfocus.com/t5/Identity-Manager-Tips/Creating-the-application-Client-ID-and-Client-Secret-from/ta-p/1776619).

Answer (score 1):

Azure Active Directory whose authentication tokens can be used as the client_id, client_secret, and tenant_id fields needed by Terraform (subscription_id can be independently recovered from your Azure account details).

It's possible to complete this task in either the [Azure CLI](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/service_principal_client_secret.html#creating-a-service-principal-using-the-azure-cli) or in the [Azure Portal](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/auth/service_principal_client_secret.html#creating-a-service-principal-in-the-azure-portal) - in both we'll create a Service Principal which has Contributor rights to the subscription. It's also possible to assign other rights depending on your configuration.

Go Portal -->click on Active Directory-->App registration--> There you will be able to find Application client Id and Directory tenant. For Secrets and click on that option.[image]